# TextAlignment for Button with HeightRequest/WidthRequest

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use an "Cancel"- und "OK"-Button with HeightRequest="35" and a WidthRequest="100".

When I have this, the Text of the Button is not aligned to the Center vertical and horizontal.

Is there a way to let the Text center based on the HeightRequest/WidthRequest without using tricks like setting Paddings appropriately?

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="35" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" HorizontalOptions="End">

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />-->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" />
            
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code and a screenshot demonstrating the problem

Comment: Code and a Screenshot is attached above - as can be seen the Text Alignments are a bit out of Shape. When adding the Padding property from the Grid.Resources it gets better, but don't think this is the best way. HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions don't help to center the Text.

Comment: use `HorizontalTextAlignment` and `VerticalTextAlignment`, although I would expect them both to default to `Center`.  It may be that your label is not big enough for it to correctly fill all of the constraints

Comment: I would have, but they do not exist on the Button  

Comment: I am sorry, I was a bit busy with other things. I think you are right with what you write about the FontSize. On one hand it makes sense that this should be smaller as the Button is smaller. On the other hand I think that the designers did not consider, that sometimes you don't want to have a smaller Font due to readability.

Your answer though is absolutely right and I marked it as answer for my problem :)
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Never mind, and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the settings about Button in Styles.xaml:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button"> 
    ...
    
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    ...
    <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="44"/>
    ...
    
</Style>
```

The default FontSize is set to "14". So, if you want to set HeightRequest of Button to "35" and keep the Text of the Button center, you need to set FontSize value to be slightly smaller than before. Such as 10:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="35" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" HorizontalOptions="End" Padding="10">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Cancel" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="OK" />
</Grid>
```

You don't need to set `FontAutoScalingEnabled`, `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions`. And here is the effect:

[image]
[image]